# SQL уникальность пары

Tags: mysql, сортировка, select

есть такой запрос :

```
SELECT DISTINCT departure_city, arrival_city
FROM routes r
JOIN aircrafts a ON r.aircraft_code = a.aircraft_code WHERE a.model = 'Boeing 
777-300'
ORDER BY 1;
```

ответ:

[image]

как можно модифицировать запрос, чтоб каждая пара повторялась только 1 раз

т.е нужно получить в ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(departure_city, arrival_city), GREATEST(departure_city, arrival_city) ...` - или UNION.

Comment: что то я не понял чем мне тут помогут least и greatest. Union же объединяет данные из двух таблиц, а у меня 1

Comment: *я не понял чем мне тут помогут least и greatest.* А попробовать? *Union же объединяет данные из двух таблиц, а у меня 1* Нет, он объединяет два набора записей - которые могут быть получены из одной и той же таблицы, но с различными условиями отбора.

Comment: да ,спасибо ,сработало. но я не понял как работает. Не подскажете как работает greatest со строками или где прочитать про это (можно на английском) ?

Comment: еще раз спасибо все понял

Comment: для данного набора данных достаточно условия `WHERE arrival_city < departure_city`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
LEAST(departure_city, arrival_city), 
GREATEST(departure_city, arrival_city)
FROM routes r 
JOIN aircrafts a 
ON r.aircraft_code = a.aircraft_code 
WHERE a.model = 'Boeing 777-300'                          
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT departure_city, arrival_city
  FROM routes r
  JOIN aircrafts a ON r.aircraft_code = a.aircraft_code
  WHERE a.model = 'Боинг 777-300'
      AND departure_city <> arrival_city
      AND arrival_city < departure_city;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Достаточно условия `WHERE arrival_city < departure_city`